# VectorField in redis schema in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis, phpredis

I am trying to create an index in redis with the following code

```
$schema = [
    new NumericField('doc_id'),
    new NumericField('entity_id'),
    new VectorField('embedding', 'HNSW', ['DIM' => 768, 'DISTANCE_METRIC' => 'COSINE']),
    new TagField('users'),
    new TagField('url'),

];
return Redis::ftCreate('testVector', $schema, []);
```

An raise this error :/

Predis\Response\ServerException
Bad arguments for algorithm HNSW: 768

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The TYPE attribute is also mandatory, but I guess it’s not the main issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, the parameters are not with keys.

```
$schema = [
        new NumericField('doc_id'),
        new NumericField('entity_id'),
        // VectorField cosine algorithm
        new VectorField('embedding', 'HNSW', ['TYPE', 'FLOAT64', 'DIM', 768, 'DISTANCE_METRIC', 'COSINE']),
        new TagField('users'),
        new TagField('url'),

    ];
```